# UIVideoEditorController ignores .videoQuality

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, avfoundation

Videos trimmed with `UIVideoEditorController` are compressed and lose quality despite setting `videoQuality` attribute in iOS 8.2 and iOS 8.3.

```
let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! UIVideoEditorController
    if let pathStr = mediaFile.pathStr {
        if UIVideoEditorController.canEditVideoAtPath(pathStr as String) {
            controller.delegate = self
            controller.videoMaximumDuration = 30
            controller.videoPath = pathStr as String
            controller.videoQuality = .TypeHigh
        } else {
            showAlert("Can not edit video")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?